# Plot proportion in bar chart grouped by another variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, data-science, geom-bar

I am currently reading `R for Data Science` and trying to create some graphs. I understand that to get proportion in bar chart, you need to use `group = 1`. For example, the code below works:

```
library(ggplot2) 

ggplot(data = diamonds) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, fill = color))
```

But I don't get the same plot for proportions.

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, fill = color, y = ..prop.., group = 1))
```

I do get proportion but not by `color`.

Comment: you don't need `tidyverse` package for this

Comment: `diamonds` is part of `ggplot2`, the only package you need for this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it using `..count..`

```
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(diamonds,aes(cut,..count../sum(..count..),fill=color))+
  geom_bar()+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent)
```

[image]